# Playing video frame by frame

Tags: android, video-processing

I want to make app with frame by frame playback feature. I guess it's not possible with standard android tools. I tried VideoView and seekTo(current + 1000/framerate) method, but it doesn't work (i guess it won't seek on paused video). My question is: What do i need to learn and use to make it possible, what tools and/or libs? I'm android beginner and i didn't work on video rendering earlier so my knowledge about this is really low.

Comment: Check out [MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime(long)). It allows you to get specific frames

Comment: @inistelm I tried it but it seems like it's not fast enough, it takes about 2-3 sec to change frame and that's definitely too long.

Comment: You might try to buffer some frames in advance so that it would look seamless to the user

Comment: @inistel, it might work but anyway I need another solution, cause i want to play video normally also. Just like Media Player Classic on pc, you play video normally but u can pause it and watch it frame by frame.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this? I'm struggling with the same problem right now. :-/

Answer (score 3):

A few years passed ,but the issue is still there

A short review about the topic:
 Assuming you have a compressed video, like mp4 file. What you asking for, is to play frame by frame, but because of the compression, the frames are not actually there (look about i,p and b frames [at this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types)). So Android need to generate this frames for you.
This generation may be far from optimal (it skipped about 3% frames in my case), and may not be supported on some devices , because there are different codecs used.

In case you are planning to run some Algo over it, I suggest extracting the frames first, as a jpg images, and then read them one by one.

I used the ffmpeg wrapper from  [here](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) by hiteshsondhi88 to archive the extraction. It's very easy to use, and works smoothly.

In case your still want to go with pure Java, there is a great job done by [Fadden](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/). There is a few examples how to use media codec and get frames.

Moreover, I've written a small example on this, that can be found at  [my Git repository](https://github.com/arkadyeye/FrameByFramePlayer)

There is also a discussion about it that in another StackOverflow  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684347/extract-all-video-frames-in-android), but I have not tried it yet, to approve.